# How to import global object App as property to nested component?

Tags: vue.js

I try to build single page application on VueJs from webpack.
I have the global app where I want to store some data (global variables  of whole Application).
I want to have access to App global object (properties and methods ) anywhere in my nested components.

I have tried to set global App as local variable app

```
import Block from "./Block";
    import App from "../../App";

    export default {
        name: 'Gallery',
        components: {Block},
        extends: Block,
        props: {
            block: Object
        },
        data() {
            return {
                title: "Gallery",
                app: App,
                editMode: false
            }
        },

        methods: {

            addPicture: function () {

                this.app.state.selectedBlock = this.block.id;
                this.app.state.showFilesStorage = true;

            },

        },
        computed: {}
    }
```

then I call addPicture() method I see

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'selectedBlock' of undefined
```

but App has this property. And I want to have access to call methods of App methods from any nested components too like this

```
this.app.getBlocks();
```

Comment: Are you using vuex for this in App?

Comment: No I haven't used vuex before.

Comment: Ok maybe you have a look at it, It's suited for this kind of scenario's https://vuex.vuejs.org/